# Javascript Browser Amazon Cognito Username/Password Login Require Issue

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

**Goal:**

Use credentials located in Amazon Cognito to successfully login using Javascript in a Google Chrome browser session.

**Problem:**

Using the [amazon cognito js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js), I  have been trying to get amazon cognito implemented in my Javascript so I can do a simple call.

I get the following error in my console.

```
require.js:5 GET file:///C:/path/amazon-cognito-identity-js.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
req.load @ require.js:5
load @ require.js:5
load @ require.js:5
fetch @ require.js:5
check @ require.js:5
enable @ require.js:5
enable @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
each @ require.js:5
enable @ require.js:5
init @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:5
o @ require.js:5
requirejs @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "amazon-cognito-identity-js"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:5:1067)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5:13218)
```

I tried adding the package via `npm install --save amazon-cognito-identity-js` but it doesn't seem to register and not sure how to get it to register. Thoughts?

If no answer can be found, I'd be interested in setting up Amazon Cognito using Javascript as it has been a train wreck trying to figure this out. (I have done this on Swift and it was nowhere near this difficult).

**Code:**

**webpack.config.js**

```json
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'my-app.js'
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require(['amazon-cognito-identity-js']);

function signIn() {
    console.log("Signing In");

    var authenticationData = {
        Username: '<username>',
        Password: '<password>',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(
        authenticationData
    );
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId: '<poolID>', // Your user pool id here
        ClientId: '<clientID>', // Your client id here
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username: '<name>',
        Pool: userPool,
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

            //POTENTIAL: Region needs to be set if not already set previously elsewhere.
            AWS.config.region = '<region>';

            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId: '...', // your identity pool id here
                Logins: {
                    // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                    'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_9jpw8F8BS': result
                        .getIdToken()
                        .getJwtToken(),
                },
            });

            //refreshes credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()
            AWS.config.credentials.refresh(error => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                } else {
                    // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
                    // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();
                    console.log('Successfully logged!');
                }
            });
        },

        onFailure: function (err) {
            alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
        },
    });
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1066.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="signIn()">Press Me</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using require, try using import statements like below. Below code snippet worked for me

```
import {
  CognitoUserPool,
  CognitoUser,
  AuthenticationDetails,
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

const login = () => {

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: // userPoolID,
  ClientId: // clientID,
});

const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
      Username: // email,
      Pool: userPool,
    });

    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: // email,
      Password: // password,
    });

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        // const accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
        cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("err", err);
            return;
          }
          console.log("name",result[2].Value)
          console.log("login success")
    
        });
      },
      onFailure: (err) => {
        console.log("login failed", err);
        // reject(err);
      },
      
    });
}
```

Below article would be helpful for you to get a better understanding on this amazon-cognito-identity-js package.
https://medium.com/@sankharathnayaka/aws-cognito-authentication-without-using-amplify-8d0e3af997c2